# Can a discontinued Office 365 subscription migrate to Outlook.com for calendar and contacts?

Tags: office365, calendar, contacts, outlook.com

I am helping with an Office 365 Business Essentials to IMAP migration. The domain owner would like to continue using Calendar and Contacts, which are available via Outlook.com. Is it possible to continue using the calendar and contacts via Outlook.com with the same Microsoft login after canceling Office 365, or will new Outlook.com accounts need to be setup with a manual migration of the Calendars and Contacts?

Is there a simple way to keep the data in Microsoft's ecosystem, or is the process I need to follow the same as if I were transferring the data to another service: ICS/CSV export, import?

Comment: You would have to download the email (plus contacts and calendar to a local PST file and then move the stuff to Outlook.com

Comment: I transferred the email with an IMAP to IMAP tool. But you're saying new Outlook.com accounts will be needed for the calendars and contacts?

Comment: I think you can import PST contacts and calendar in Outlook.com

Comment: Office365 is not the same as outlook.com, so in any case, you will have to migrate and create a new account.

Comment: Using a domain with outlook.com (hotmail.com) is no longer free, it has not been free, for nearly a decade.  So while it is possible to use the domain, it's not free, exact costs can be quoted researched.

Comment: My mistake was thinking O365 accounts are in any way connected to live.com accounts.  But if not, then it makes sense the accounts will be completely deleted and not downgrade. @LPChip, please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Office365 is not the same as outlook.com, so in any case, you will have to migrate and create a new account.

You can have an email account both work with an Office365 subscription and as microsoft account though, but when you login for a microsoft service, it will ask you if you are referring to the business (office365) or personal (microsoft live) account.